# look for the similarity of words in sentences javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to find the similarity between the sentences in javascript, example :

```
let mastersentences = "Gambir, Kecamatan Gambir, Kota Jakarta Pusat, Daerah Khusus Ibukota Jakarta";
let keywordsentences = "DKI JAKARTA";
let result = ( mastersentences  === keywordsentences ) // true because 'jakarta' is match
```

the result of equating 'mastersentence' and 'keywordsentence' is "jakarta", i have try using more method of javascript but i still can't find the result like use :

```
includes()
indexOf()
lastIndexOf()
localeCompare()
match()
search()
```

Comment: In which condition do the two sentences have a similarity, if one-word match?

Comment: @Mina yes, if one-word match.

Comment: There's no built-in function which will perform your custom logic.  You would have to either write that logic yourself or use some 3rd party language processing tool that has logic similar enough to yours.  In this case it sounds like your "match" is if one string contains any word from the other string (split by spaces), case-insensitive.

Comment: [`split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) the `keywordsentences` string value at every whitespace (sequence) into an array of words to be searched for in `mastersentences`. For the array of words search if [`some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) word is [`includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes)/ed within `mastersentences`.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You can `split` each sentence by `\W+` which any character isn't text or number or underscore, and use `some` method, to check if there are any matches after converting each work to `lower case` to prevent sensitivity.

```js
let mastersentences = "Gambir, Kecamatan Gambir, Kota Jakarta Pusat, Daerah Khusus Ibukota Jakarta";
let keywordsentences = "DKI JAKARTA";
const keywordsentencesArray = keywordsentences.toLowerCase()


const result = mastersentences.toLowerCase().split(/\W+/).some(w => keywordsentencesArray.includes(w))

console.log(result)
```

Comment: @riski ... `some` used twice unnecessarily forces an avoidable `split` and an avoidable `toLowerCase`.

Comment: Also the tests are run twice

Comment: @PeterSeliger, mplungjan, Thanks for notifying me, It will not affect the functionality, but it will affect the performance if the text is very large, I just update the answer.

Comment: @Mina ... another note after the updated above answer ... lower casing `mastersentences` is enough; it does not need to be split additionally since `includes` is not only an `Array` but also a `String` method.

Comment: @PeterSeliger However that will give result when mastercard is compared with master

Answer (score 0):

My answer uses [.match()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) with a regular expression made from the `mastersentences` which is previously cleaned from any punctuation or special characters *(There could be some other I did not think of... Up to you to add them)*.

The output is a boolean false if no match were found.

```js
const mastersentences = "Gambir, Kecamatan Gambir, Kota Jakarta Pusat, Daerah Khusus Ibukota Jakarta";
const keywordsentences = "DKI JAKARTA";
const noMatchSentence = "Hello world!"

function compare(master, sentence) {
  const words = sentence.replace(/[,\.:;\!\?'"\(\)\{\}~\|]/g, "").split(" ")
  const re = new RegExp(`\\b(${words.join('|')})\\b`, 'gi')
  return master.match(re) !== null
}

console.log(compare(mastersentences, keywordsentences)) // true
console.log(compare(mastersentences, noMatchSentence))  // false
```

Answer (score -1):

I assume, you want to get True with your matching, if any Keyword is found in the `mastersentence`.

This is done by splitting the Keywords from a string to a Array, as we can iterate through all Keywords this way.
We then try to find any keyword in the sentence, in my case is the search case-insensitive. This means, it does not care if the Keyword was capitalized or all capital letters.

If any Keyword is found in the `mastersentence` we return a boolean value true and false otherwise.

```js
// Our sentence to match the Keywords against
let mastersentences = "Gambir, Kecamatan Gambir, Kota Jakarta Pusat, Daerah Khusus Ibukota Jakarta";

// Our Keywords to match in a sentence
let keywordsentences = "DKI JAKARTA";


function matchKeyword(sentence, keywords){
  // It is easier to match the keywords against a senctence, if those are stored in an array
  if(typeof keywords === "string") keywords = keywords.split(" ");
  
  // We transform the sentence to all lowercase, so we can match keywords character-wise
  // If you dont want it to be case-insensitive, you should remove the '.toLowerCase()'-line 
  // here and further down by the keywords
  sentence = sentence.toLowerCase();
  
  // We check every keyword if it is anywhere in the sentence.
  // Arry.prototype.find() returns the first suffice keyword that exists in the sentence
  // With the double Exclamation mark we cast the result to a boolean value so we get true if any 
  // keyword was found and false if none were found in the sentence
  return !!keywords.find(keyword => sentence.indexOf(keyword.toLowerCase()) >= 0);
}


// We try matching the Keywords against the sentence
console.log(matchKeyword(mastersentences, keywordsentences))
```

Answer (score -1):

From the above comment ...

> *[`split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) the `keywordsentences` string value at every whitespace (sequence) into an array of words to be searched for in `mastersentences`. For the array of words search if [`some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) word is [`includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes)/ed within `mastersentences`.*

In addition to the suggested all lower case based search via `includes` and `some`, one also could combine `some` with a [`RegExp`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp)-based case-insensitive [`test`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test).

```js
const mastersentence = "Gambir, Kecamatan Gambir, Kota Jakarta Pusat, Daerah Khusus Ibukota Jakarta";
const keywords = "DKI JAKARTA";

const lowerCaseMaster = mastersentence.toLowerCase();

console.log(
  keywords
    // - lower case `keywords` first.
    .toLowerCase()
    // - then split the lower cased string
    //   value at every whitespace sequence.
    .split(/\s+/g)
    // - then look for at least a single occurrence 
    //   of a lower cased keyword item ...
    .some(keyword =>
      // ... within the lower cased master via `includes`.
      lowerCaseMaster.includes(keyword)
    )
);
console.log(
  keywords
    .split(/\s+/g)
    .some(keyword =>
      // case insensitive regex based search.
      RegExp(`\\b${ keyword }\\b`, 'i').test(mastersentence)
    )
)
```

Comment: I didn't downvote your answer, but all cases will fail if you just add `,` in keywords, `const keywords = "DKI JAKARTA,";`

Comment: "DKI JAKARTA, somthing"

Answer (score -2):

Filter and some

```js
let master = "Gambir, Kecamatan Gambir, Kota Jakarta Pusat, Daerah Khusus Ibukota Jakarta".split(/,\s+/);
let keywords = "DKI JAKARTA".split(/\s+/);

console.log(
  master.filter(sentence => sentence.split(/\s+/)
    .some(word => keywords.includes(word.toUpperCase()))
  )
  .length>0
)
```

Comment: (Sorry i f you saw my comment, it was meant for the other answer)

Comment: thanks for the answer , i just search the result if is true or false

Comment: I added .length>0 to return a boolean

Comment: No popular answer here

Comment: This function will not work if there are multiple spaces. as it will compare spaces and it will always be true. For example `let master = " ".split(", ");
let keywords = "DKI  JAKARTA".split(" ");` will return `true`

Comment: @Mina that is trivial to fix. So I did.

Comment: Any bug will be trivial to fix if you know the cause of the bug.

Comment: For sure, he gives an example of the text, and he wants a general rule, and I didn't downvote you.